# CSS: Circle with dynamic number in p tag

Tags: html, css

I have a list of usernames:

```
<p>user 1</p>
<p>user 2</p>
<p>user 3</p>
```

My goal is to display the number of recommendations a user has received in a small circle right next to the user name, with the same height as the text.

I have set up a jsfiddle, but don't know how to achieve my goal:

http://jsfiddle.net/hAxJp/

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: r u looking something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/hAxJp/1/

Comment: you mean notification like appear in mobile device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/hAxJp/3/)

```
<p>user <span>1</span></p>
<p>user <span>2</span></p>
<p>user <span>3</span></p>

span{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    background: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try use counter-reset:

Sets the identifier that will store counter mappings specific element and the initial value of the counter. This counter can be displayed using the content and properties of pseudo: after and: before.

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zHCLh)

**HTML**

```
 <div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2>
      some text
    </h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure molestiae ab impedit assumenda aut magni tenetur nulla deserunt? Saepe consectetur obcaecati laboriosam excepturi voluptate nam sit facilis aut laborum quo?</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>
      some text
    </h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure molestiae ab impedit assumenda aut magni tenetur nulla deserunt? Saepe consectetur obcaecati laboriosam excepturi voluptate nam sit facilis aut laborum quo?</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>
      some text
    </h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure molestiae ab impedit assumenda aut magni tenetur nulla deserunt? Saepe consectetur obcaecati laboriosam excepturi voluptate nam sit facilis aut laborum quo?</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>
      some text
    </h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure molestiae ab impedit assumenda aut magni tenetur nulla deserunt? Saepe consectetur obcaecati laboriosam excepturi voluptate nam sit facilis aut laborum quo?</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>
      some text
    </h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure molestiae ab impedit assumenda aut magni tenetur nulla deserunt? Saepe consectetur obcaecati laboriosam excepturi voluptate nam sit facilis aut laborum quo?</p>
  </li>
   <li>
    <h2>
      some text
    </h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure molestiae ab impedit assumenda aut magni tenetur nulla deserunt? Saepe consectetur obcaecati laboriosam excepturi voluptate nam sit facilis aut laborum quo?</p>
  </li>
</ul>  
  </div>
```

Comment: if yes add yelement list will be immediately added her number

Comment: can, but I understood his question as

Comment: problem is number could be dynamic. how that will be control?

Comment: first counter is reset, and then adding the list and added one by